# Extracting strings from list on multiple conditions

Tags: python, string, list

I have the following list:

```
fields = ['angDist','angDist','_RAJ2000','_DEJ2000','NVSS','RAJ2000',
                  'DEJ2000','e_RAJ2000','e_DEJ2000','S1.4','e_S1.4','l_MajAxis',
                  'MajAxis','l_MinAxis','MinAxis','f_resFlux','_RAJ2000',
                  '_DEJ2000','GLEAM','RAJ2000','DEJ2000','Fpwide','Fintwide',
                  'eabsFpct','efitFpct','Fp076','Fint076','Fp084','Fint084',
                  'Fp092','Fint092','Fp099','Fint099','Fp107','Fint107','Fp115',
                  'Fint115','Fp122','Fint122','Fp130','Fint130','Fp143',
                  'Fint143','Fp151','Fint151','Fp158','Fint158','Fp166',
                  'Fint166','Fp174','Fint174','Fp181','Fint181','Fp189',
                  'Fint189','Fp197','Fint197','Fp204','Fint204','Fp212',
                  'Fint212','Fp220','Fint220','Fp227','Fint227','alpha',
                  'Fintfit200','RAdeg','DEdeg','errHalfMaj','errHalfMin',
                  'errPosAng','objID','mode','q_mode','class','SDSS12',
                  'm_SDSS12','flags','ObsDate','Q','umag','e_umag','gmag',
                  'e_gmag','rmag','e_rmag','imag','e_imag','zmag','e_zmag','zsp',
                  'e_zsp','f_zsp','zph','e_zph','avg_zph','pmRA','e_pmRA','pmDE',
                  'e_pmDE','SpObjID','spType','spCl','subClass'
]
```

and I need to extract a list of the strings starting with `Fp` or ending with `mag`, but not starting with `e_`.

I've tried a list comprehension:

```
    magnames1 = [mag for mag in fields if mag.startswith('Fp')]
    magnames2 = [mag for mag in fields if (mag.endswith('mag') && !(mag.startswith"e_"))]
    magnames = magnames1 + magnames2
```

but `magnames2` gives me a syntax error. What's the easiest way to do this without hardcoding the strings into another list?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: `magnames2 = [mag for mag in fields if mag.endswith('mag') and not mag.startswith("e_")]` . (Note that you might end up with duplication in your concatenated list, although not with this particular sample data. You could convert to a set to eliminate the duplicates.)

Comment: No `&&`s in Python; use the `and` operator. Also, no `!`s in Python, use the `not` operator.
What it should be: `magnames2 = [mag for mag in fields if (mag.endswith('mag') and not mag.startswith("e_"))]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `and` instead of `&&` and `not` instead of `!`:

```
magnames1 = [mag for mag in fields if mag.startswith('Fp')]
magnames2 = [mag for mag in fields if (mag.endswith('mag') and not mag.startswith("e_"))]
magnames = magnames1 + magnames2
```

Comment: Oh I tried that and it didn't work, but I had a parenthesis in the wrong place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use the keyword `not` instead of `!` and a single `&` instead of `&&`.